# CSV Import Is not working after deploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csv, hosting

I am trying to import data from CSV file and storing it into the database. This functionality is working perfectly in local but when i host it in GoDaddy it's not working.
My website is hosted in GoDaddy and database in Azure.

Comment: You will need to provide way more information than this. My first guess though would be SQL azure firewall settings

Comment: I am trying to import data from CSV files and storing those data into the database. My code is working locally but when i have hosted my application. it's not working. I think, i need to change permission settings on azure. If you know about it anything please help me out.

Comment: I'd look at Azure first, if you goto the database settings in the Azure portal, select the database you're working with then on the right hand side low down on the page there should be a link to 'Manage allowed IP addresses' you will have to put the IP address of the GoDaddy server so that the Azure firewall lets it through.

Comment: I did try that but it's not working.

Comment: So you need to give more information then or no one will be able to help you. Have you tried putting a Try/Catch block around your code and outputting the exception somewhere? You could update your question with it and that would give people a clue as to what the problem is!

Comment: I have Database in AZURE and my application is hosted on GoDaddy.
When i connect Azure database in my local machine then CSV is working. But it's not working in GoDaddy hosting. So What i understood is - issue is occurring because of GoDaddy. I don't think so there is any problem with azure.
Are there any libraries that need to add in GoDaddy server??

Comment: Are you just ignoring what I've said?? I've told you to check the managed ip addresses, did you? Did you check that the godaddy ip address is listed there? Did you try putting a Try/Catch block around your code? Do those two things and we might get to bottom of issue, without I cannot help

Comment: I told you " 
I did try that but it's not working.".

Comment: I learnt that i need to change some kind of Collation so that it encode UTC-8. This is just a little hint. I have tried to change but failed.